# Estilos API POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Tengo :

```
CellStyle style = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();

HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)number);
cell.setCellValue(text)
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Me gustaria que el fondo sea de color gris por ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
CellStyle style = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();

//cambiar el fondo
style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)number);
cell.setCellValue(text)
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

Con este metodo puedes agregar el color.

```
protected CellStyle setCellBackground(CellStyle cellStyle, Short color) {
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    return cellStyle;
}
```

Para el color gris es :

```
HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index
```